# Uml-Designer Plugin-Installation doesn't work on eclipse

Tags: uml-designer

The uml designer plugin installation doesnt work. 
Eclipse "cannot perform operation", after i choose the uml designer items to install. The installtion results in a error, cannot find the requestet items from the link. the link is the update site link from the homepage.
Its like the download link would be broken...any suggestions?

Details of the error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: UML Designer with Product Specific Branding 8.0.0.201709181143 (org.obeonetwork.dsl.uml2.runtime.product.feature.feature.group 8.0.0.201709181143)
>
> Missing requirement: UML Designer with Product Specific Branding 8.0.0.201709181143 (org.obeonetwork.dsl.uml2.runtime.product.feature.feature.group 8.0.0.201709181143) requires 'org.eclipse.sirius.runtime.acceleo.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: Please format the error by adding 4 leading space to each line of error.

Answer (score 8):

Install Sirius from Eclipse marketplace. As the UML desginer is based on the Sirius. This resolved issue.

UmlDesigner plugins depends on another eclipse plugin called "Sirius".

Comment: Installation confirmed for Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a release. Now as for using the modelling tool, that's a different story...